# How to Edit the Pub/Sub url after publishing the application

Tags: publish-subscribe, jawbone

We published the wrong Pub/Sub url by mistake. How can we edit the Pub/Sub url after publishing the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change a URL for a published app, please email apisupport @ jawbone.com for assistance.

When an app is published, any UP user can connect to that app. For this reason, Jawbone chooses to err on the side of security for the user's data and requires a manual review of any app changes.